# Backstage Button doesn't close Backstage

Tags: wpf, fluent-ribbon

In Office 2010  when a Backstage button is pressed the Backstage would automatically close.  For example I have a Backstage with New, Open and Save buttons.

When I click on a button the Backstage is not being closed - I suppose that's not the correct behavior. How can I let Fluent-Ribbon handle the Backstage correct?

I'm using the current release 2.0 from november 2010 (http://fluent.codeplex.com/releases/view/55556).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a defect in the ribbon that is fixed in the latest version in sound control, but not yet in the latest released version.

For now you can work around this using the following

```
// During initialisation
myRibbon.Menu.AddHandler(PopupService.DismissPopupEvent, (DismissPopupEventHandler)OnPopupDismiss);

private void OnPopupDismiss(object sender, DismissPopupEventArgs e)
{
    var backstage = Menu as Backstage;
    if (backstage != null)
    {
        backstage.IsOpen = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there any plans for a new release? I don't feel like compile the source myself.

Comment: @nyn3x I don't have a clue (I'm not afiliated with the project), however you don't need to modify the Fluent source code to apply this fix - just apply it to your ribbon instance (where `myRibbon` is your ribbon instance)

Answer (score 1):

In Ribbon.xml the attribute required is `isDefinitive=""true""` not sure how Fluent-Ribbon handles that, but is should have the equivalent

Comment: Well, `Fluent:Button`also has a `IsDefinitive` attribut; but setting that to `true` doesn't seem to have any effect.